# How store coordinates of boundaries of each zone region in a London tube map .GIF file?

Tags: processing, kml, data-visualization, mouse-coordinates

I am trying to:

1. Generate a KML file that stores the coordinates of each boundary zone region of London tube map.
2. Store x,y coordinates as key-pair values to store points of each station on each line.

A KML eventually would look like this:

```
<nameOfLine>
 <zoneNumber>
     <zoneregionCoords>
       <stationName>
             <xCoords></xCoords>
             <yCoords></yCoords>
       </stationName>
    </zoneregionCoords>
 </zoneNumber>
</nameOfLine>
```

Is there a tool to trace the region coordinates of mouse movements (read) from the GIF file onto a KML file? Is there a way I can specifiy the element tags at the same time in the KML file?

The whole objective is to generate this KML file with minimal code.

I am going to use Processing after I have generated the KML file, to give visualization for data to be displayed on the London tube map.gif file.

Comment: Can you post a link to the .gif?

Comment: The structure you describe is a xml format but certainly is not KML. In kml terminology you need to create placemarks. In your case linestrings for the areas and points for the stations. If you want to create a kml file by clicking with the mouse why not simply use the google earth client? I must be missing something here

Comment: @ Szab link http://www.bbc.co.uk/london/travel/downloads/tube_map.gif

Comment: @ Eddy yes u are quite correct abt it. I agree wit d KML but this tube map (refr link) does nt rq geocoords, but i may hv 2 prepare my own schema instead, but i need to plot the screen coords so as to get an accurate polyg-region zone . Many they are the better accuracy. But how can i do this, I hv already got the suggestion to use Processing to code the program to trace the screen coords and feed them in2 text file, that would b time consuming 4 me with ltd knowledge. Wish it could b easy 2 use a lasso tool(Photoshop) to select the polyregions and a tool autogenerates the coords. get d idea?

Comment: Again this is nothing do with Google Maps or Google Earth, its Processing i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [Plot Digitizer](http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/) to record the coordinates of mouse clicks, then process the final coordinate list with another tool to create a KML.

Alternatively you could create an image overlay in Google Earth using that GIF, align it, then use Google Earth to create the points.

Comment: I am unable to understand this by just right clicking 3 points for zone 9 and then what do I do?